# Outer join help in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have:

```
select title, order#, STATE
from customers C, ORDERITEMS O, books b
where b.ISBN=O.ISBN (+)
order by title
```

But I'm trying to understand why rows that don't have order# have state

```
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY   1003    CA
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY   1003    WY
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY   1003    TX
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY   1003    NY
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY   1003    WA
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY   1003    ID
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY   1003    FL
BUILDING A CAR WITH TOOTHPICKS  -   FL
BUILDING A CAR WITH TOOTHPICKS  -   NJ
BUILDING A CAR WITH TOOTHPICKS  -   GA
BUILDING A CAR WITH TOOTHPICKS  -   MI
```

Comment: Are you sure the order number is really empty? A dash (`-` character) is not the same as `NULL`. Apart from that: please indicate from which tables the three columns are taken.

Comment: @Arjan Yeah I rolled back, I think the OP edited the same time as you. I guess we will see who's rollback takes precedence.

Comment: So what do I enter to format code?

Comment: What does the dash mean then? Also, order# isn't nullable.

Comment: books->title, customers ->state, ORDERITEMS->order#

Comment: For formatting help see the right margin while editing, or click the question mark above the editor while editing. As the latter might not be shown on a mobile device: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (So: indent with 4 spaces, and ensure a blank line above it.)

Comment: I'd have to type 4 spaces before each line?

Comment: You wouldn't have *to type them*. Select the whole block and hit Ctrl-K or click the little `{}` button (hint: see the tooltips when hovering your mouse over the button bar). But: you can read, can't you? So, AGAIN, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, like I wrote above! (And, BEWARE: there is a strict screening in place that eventually bans accounts from posting new questions when it thinks the quality of existing posts is too low. So: take some time to learn about it, if you think it applies to you. Not informing yourself will eventually get you into trouble. Success!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using 3 tables, but only one join. That will get you too many results. You will need two joins: probably somehow table Customers needs to be joined with OrderItems too.

Something like:

```
and o.customerId = c.id
```

Hence:

```
select b.title, o.order#, c.state
from customers c, orderitems o, books b
where o.customerId = c.id
and b.isbn = o.isbn (+)
order by title
```

Answer (score 4):

I find it a lot easier to use ANSI joins if more than one table is involved when doing outer joins:

```
SELECT title, order#, STATE
FROM customers c 
   JOIN orderitems O ON o.customer_id = c.id
   LEFT JOIN books b ON b.isbn = o.isbn
ORDER BY title
```

(this is essentially the same query that Arjan posted, just with standard syntax)

Depending on your needs you might want to use a LEFT JOIN for orderitems as well e.g. if you also want customers that do not have orderitems

It is also good practice to use the table alias for the columns in the select list as well. Doing that makes the statement easier to understand (because you immediately know from which table which column comes) and it's more stable against changes.

Comment: With an `on` in the 3rd line too, I assume?