# What's the meaning of '-' in oracle output?

Tags: oracle10g

Sometimes I get a dash in output but I was told it's not a null, so what is it?

select title, order#, STATE
from customers C, ORDERITEMS O, books b
where b.ISBN=O.ISBN (+)
order by title

```
CUSTOMERS:
Column Name Data Type   Nullable    Default Primary Key
CUSTOMER#   NUMBER(4,0) No  -   1
LASTNAME    VARCHAR2(10)    Yes -   -
FIRSTNAME   VARCHAR2(10)    Yes -   -
ADDRESS VARCHAR2(20)    Yes -   -
CITY    VARCHAR2(12)    Yes -   -
STATE   VARCHAR2(2) Yes -   -
ZIP VARCHAR2(5) Yes -   -
REFERRED    NUMBER(4,0) Yes -   -
```

Comment: what column type returns the dash? - can you post table ddl and query?

Comment: SEE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426177/outer-join-help-in-oracle

Comment: What tool are you using to run the query? TOAD? SQL Developer? SQL*Plus? It looks like your tool is replacing NULLs with "-" in the output.

Comment: I'm using Database Home Page>SQL>SQL Commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you select '-' from dual, the output will be "-".

If this is not the answer you are looking for, consider posting your query and maybe the DDL of the table in question.

I agree with  user490735, it looks like his link has the answer.  Also, ANSI join syntax is mucn easier (at least for me) to read.

The dash appears to be a place holder for null columns in the outer join.  As a long shot, if the default value of the nullable columns is actually '-' (I don't think it is) then you will get the dash in your query results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you posted the output of a "describe," not the output of the query. The describe is simply telling you there is no default value for any of the columns and which columns are not part of the primary key.

Comment: the output of the query is in the link in my comment above.